# Function Level Reset notification to Linux PCIe device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci-e

This query is regarding Function level reset feature for SRIOV.
As per code in Linux PCIe driver the function level reset is done by writing `1` to `reset` under sysfs interface:

`echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/pci_interface_id/reset`

As function level reset is not triggered via the PCIe device driver how PCIe device driver can get the notification of the function level reset(FLR)?

Comment: Writing to sysfs triggers the `store` callback in the driver.

Comment: Hi stark, are you referring store callback as the "reset_store" in pci-sysfs.c? . This function reset_store does not have any call to PCIe device driver (  PCIe device driver = device specific driver like the ixgbe driver from intel)

Comment: Then what does `pci_reset_function` do?

Comment: reset_store calls pci_reset_function for FLR